# document.forms[0].onsubmit is not fully working correctly ... what's the issue?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using `document.forms[0].onsubmit` in my code to check if two duplicate values exist in the text field on my applications. If a user enters two numbers that are the same, then when you click on submit, an alert box pops up telling you that two numbers are the same. THAT part works fine, but after changing the values and having different numbers, I still get the same text from the alert box saying that the two numbers are the same. it looks like my change is not recognized at all after the first error has been corrected. How can I actually make the submit process recognize that a change to the error was made.  Below is the relevant code; I would like to be able to correct this in JavaScript with the code I already have if possible:

```
if(duplicate(esnList)){
  document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () { 
      alert ("ERROR: You can have duplicate ESNs in the ESN text field."); 
      return false; 
  }
}



<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Provision Unit(s)" tabindex="13">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the check inside the function.

```
  document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () { 
    if(duplicate(esnList)) {
      alert ("ERROR: You can have duplicate ESNs in the ESN text field."); 
      return false; 
    }
  }
```

Instead of conditionally providing a callback that always displays the error message, you have to always provide a callback that conditionally displays the message.

Comment: It doesn't work .. it's still doing that .. it's still showing me the alert even after correcting the error

Comment: @epascarello  I would like to keep the alert of both when I'm notified the error when I try to get to the next text field to type in .. and the submit alert too .. The code Kos gave me above now works ONLY on submit .. but I'd also like it to work by firing an alert right after typing the error on the text field and moving on the next one

Comment: so add the check like the answer and you can call the function when they change it.

Comment: @epascarello What do u exactly mean ? can u show me what ur trying to say ?